# Cannot allocate block number in ZooKeeper: Coordination::Exception: Connection loss

Tags: clickhouse

When I write data into my clickhouse using jdbc for 1000 0000 records, it throws an exception.

And I find my zookeeper is still alive. Could anyone tell me why the connection is lost.
Thank u.

```
i: 6999998
i: 6999999
i: 7000000
Wed Jul 07 17:25:40 CST 2021
ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseException: ClickHouse exception, code: 999, host: 10.10.1.1, port: 8123; Code: 999, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot allocate block number in ZooKeeper: Coordination::Exception: Connection loss (version 21.6.3.14 (official build))

        at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:59)
        at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:29)
        at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.checkForErrorAndThrow(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:1094)
        at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:1061)
        at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:1026)
        at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:1019)
        at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHousePreparedStatementImpl.executeBatch(ClickHousePreparedStatementImpl.java:381)
        at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHousePreparedStatementImpl.executeBatch(ClickHousePreparedStatementImpl.java:364)
        at com.chris.slient.clickhouse.App.test11(App.java:304)
        at com.chris.slient.clickhouse.App.main(App.java:441)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Code: 999, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot allocate block number in ZooKeeper: Coordination::Exception: Connection loss (version 21.6.3.14 (official build))

        at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:54)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: Check zookeeper logs.

Comment: ```2021-07-07 17:25:34,056 [myid:1] - WARN  [SyncThread:1:FileTxnLog@393] - fsync-ing the write ahead log in SyncThread:1 took 3060ms which will adversely effect operation latency.File size is 67108880 bytes. See the ZooKeeper troubleshooting guide
2021-07-07 17:25:44,298 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:2181)(secure=disabled):Follower@131] - Exception when following the leader
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)```